# javascript adding onended event in audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, audio

I hope this is not considered to be duplicate, cuz I've searched many related questions to my problem. Still I'm complete noob in javarscript and jquery so take that in mind.

I have the following code in which everything works right, but after the audio file finish, the icon is not changing to "play" and the file doesn't reload.
I've tried to add the onended event, but I'm not sure exactly where and how to do it. This will help BIG time to my project and I'll appreciate any help. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>


</head>
<body>

<div class="btn btn-xs" id="btn1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>

<div class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>

<div class="btn btn-xs" id="btn3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>


<!-- SOUNDS -->
<audio id="sound1">
    <source src="http://www.internetdj.com/mp3/108215.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio id="sound2">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0580.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<audio id="sound3">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0003.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>


</body>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('id').replace(/btn/, '');
        var play = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>';
        var pause = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i></div>';
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.html(pause);
            $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id - 1].play();
        } else {
            $this.html(play);
            $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id - 1].pause();
            $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id - 1].pause();
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want something like this [http://jsbin.com/kirifu/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/kirifu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @GarvitMangal in future if you're going to make sample audio code, use shorter sounds! 5 mins! really????

Comment: @GarvitMangal Thank you so much, sir! It's exactly what I was looking for!  
Really thankful!

Comment: @Vi0nik Welcome Buddy and I am updating it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS

```
 $('.aud').bind("ended",function(){
  var btn_id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/sound/,'');
  btn_id = "btn" + btn_id;
  var play = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>';
        var pause = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i></div>';


  $("#"+btn_id).toggleClass('active');

  if(!$("#"+btn_id).hasClass('active')){
    $("#"+btn_id).html(play);
  }


  alert("finished");
});
```

```js
$('.btn').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('id').replace(/btn/, '');
        var play = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>';
        var pause = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i></div>';
        $this.toggleClass('active');
        if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.html(pause);
            $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id - 1].play();
        } else {
            $this.html(play);
            $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id - 1].pause();
            $('audio[id^="sound"]')[id - 1].pause();
        }
    });

$('.aud').bind("ended",function(){
  var btn_id = $(this).attr("id").replace(/sound/,'');
  btn_id = "btn" + btn_id;
  var play = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>';
        var pause = '<div class="btn btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></i></div>';
  
  
  $("#"+btn_id).toggleClass('active');
  
  if(!$("#"+btn_id).hasClass('active')){
    $("#"+btn_id).html(play);
  }
  
  
  alert("finished");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="btn btn-xs" id="btn1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>

<div class="btn btn-xs" id="btn2"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>

<div class="btn btn-xs" id="btn3"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></div>


<!-- SOUNDS -->
<audio id="sound1" class="aud">
    <source src="http://www.internetdj.com/mp3/108215.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio id="sound2" class="aud">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0580.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>

<audio id="sound3" class="aud">
    <source src="http://www.bigsoundbank.com/sounds/ogg/0003.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
</body>
```

DEMO : http://jsbin.com/kirifu/edit?html,js,output